# what is the significance of (k<<24)>>>24 in remote sensing image reading?

Tags: java, image-processing

In general, why do we first left-shifted it only to be right-shifted again?
Is it related to something like ensuring that pixel value is positive?
code Snipped->

```
for(k=0; k<Width; k++)
{
    if(shiftFlag != 8)
    {
        p1 = pix_rgb[i][2*k] << 24;
        p2 = (pix_rgb[i][2*k+1] <<24 ) >>> 8;
        tempCount = p1 | p2;
        tempCount = tempCount >>> 16;
    }
    else
        tempCount = (pix_rgb[i][k] << 24) >>> 24;

    if(tempCount>maxBand[i])
        maxBand[i]=tempCount;

    if(tempCount<minBand[i])
       minBand[i]=tempCount;
}
```

Comment: Is `pix_rgb` using 24-bit values? It's probably an `int[]` but how is the RGB colour represented in each array entry?

Comment: Assuming it's an `int`,  `(x<<24)>>>24` is just an unusual way to write `x&255`

Comment: There is not much intelligence in the code; I almost hesitate to say it, but maybe bit masking with `&` was unfamiliar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on name of `pix_rgb` I am assuming that `pix_rgb[i][k]` holds an `int` represesnting color which usually on 32 bits (which is size of `int`) is written in form

```
AAAAAAAARRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGBBBBBBBB
|       |       |       |
|       |       |       blue
|       |       green
|       red
alpha/transparency
```

By `pix_rgb[i][k] << 24` you are shifting all bits to left and set most right 24 bits to 0.

So `AAAAAAAARRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGBBBBBBBB` will become

```
BBBBBBBB000000000000000000000000
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <<24
```

Now with `(pix_rgb[i][k] << 24) >>> 24` you can think of it as `BBBBBBBB000000000000000000000000 >>> 24` where you are shifting bits to right but at the same time you are guaranteed that most left bits will be filled with 0 (if we would use `>> 24` we could fill it with 1 if first `B` would also be 1).

So `BBBBBBBB000000000000000000000000` will be changed into

```
000000000000000000000000BBBBBBBB
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ >>>24
```

In other words we got `int` which holds value which represents **only** blue color.

---

In short

- `pix_rgb[i][k] << 24` was used to remove all bits except `BBBBBBBB`
- `>>>24` was used to set `BBBBBBBB` back at lower indexes of `int` so we could treat it as value from range 0-255.